# iPhone / Android Apps & interacting with a website

Tags: iphone, android

Does it matter much what your website is programmed in (PHP/.NET/ROR etc) with regards to having an iPhone or Android app interact with it?

Comment: Hi, please elaborate "interacting". If you mean browsing, than it doesn't matter, as long the your mentioned languages/frameworks provide browser independent html/javascript.

Comment: Nope :) Just use the language you like the most and fits your requirements the best. Some tasks might be easier to implement in one specific language. But generally, the languages you mention do all work for the common tasks, like database requests. It just depends on your knowledge and facilities (webhost).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't matter and if you are trying to build a mobile browser based app, then it won't matter. But if that website provides API , then you can create your app however you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making use of service calls, you need to bother about the service request/response formats (xml/json...) and its parsing methods... you need not to worry about the language used to implement those services.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not matter at all.